# Test data in GraphQL API response using protractor

Tags: angular, protractor, graphql, e2e-testing

I have an **Angular 7** application, which consumes **GraphQL** APIs. I'm using Protractor for E2E testing.

I want to check the response result coming from the API when called after login. How can I check GraphQL response data through the e2e protractor?

GQL Endpoint I wish to hit:

```
export const CurrentPersonQuery = gql`
    query CurrentPersonQuery($cdn_links: Boolean) {
        currentPerson {
            ...
            email
            full_name
            id
            status
            ...
        }
    }
`;
```

**P.S. - There are resources for testing REST APIs, but I couldn't find one for Graph APIs.**

Comment: You could do a post request with the gql query and test it just like how you would do for a REST API.

Comment: Did you encounter any specific issue ?

Comment: @DhananjaiPai I don't know how can I make a GrahQL API call from `.spec.ts` file. Do you have some resource which I failed to find on the web? or you can post some example you know will help.

Comment: GraphQL is not magic, it behaves like any other POST request in REST. The body should follow the graphQL query syntax and the response will follow a similar pattern. Do not complicate things!

Comment: Just do exactly what @DhananjaiPai suggested. Use node's `http` module and just make a request the exact same way your app does. Also, don't put this in your `.spec.ts`. Put it in a helper class/function and return whatever data you need from the response to your test.